# Duplicate entry '2014-02-28' for key 1 Error Code : 1062

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting following error please help me whats the reason
Duplicate entry '2014-02-28' for key 1

```
CREATE TABLE `th_userinfo` (
  `user_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `fb_id` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `age` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `prefix` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `utm_source` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `utm_content` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `utm_medium` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `utm_campaign` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `app_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `access_token` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `modified_access_token` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `user_browser` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `is_token_expire` varchar(250) default 'No',
  `education` varchar(350) default NULL,
  `work` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

**QUERY**

```
UPDATE th_userinfo
    SET prefix='0311', mobile='1111111', STATUS='B'
    WHERE user_id='1615972863'
```

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Added mysql tag because the backticks are characteristics of MySQL.

Comment: pls show the table with values....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a trigger on that table which inserts/updates values in some other table. This is probably what causes the issue and not the original update on the current `th_userinfo` table.

Comment: Yes there are triggers so what should I do to update?

Comment: Check what these triggers do. The current update is OK but has side effect on some other table, that's where the problem occurs.

Comment: Event_object_tableEvent_manipulationAction_timingAction_statement
th_userinfoUPDATEAFTER
BEGIN
    IF OLD.STATUS <> NEW.STATUS THEN
INSERT INTO th_user_info_logs (ACTION,user_id,firstname,lastname,fb_id,email,gender,age,city,prefix,mobile,created,STATUS,access_token,modified_access_token)
VALUES('update',NEW.user_id,NEW.firstname,NEW.lastname,NEW.fb_id,NEW.email,NEW.gender,NEW.age,NEW.city,NEW.prefix,NEW.mobile,NEW.created,NEW.STATUS,NEW.access_token,NEW.modified_access_token);
  
  END IF;
   END

Comment: BEGIN
insert into th_dates (th_dates) values (now());
    END

Comment: Right, so one of these inserts is causing the duplicate key error.